# jQuery - How to apply .animate() and .show('slide') at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In this demo http://jsfiddle.net/vHcXN you can see that wjen you click on the link a transitions starts. First the div height changes and then the slide effect.

How can I make both works at the same time?

```
 $(".turn_next").click(function(){
     $(".box2").hide();
     $(".box1_content").animate({height:'300px'}, 300,function(){
         $(".box3").show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 500);
     });
 });

 $(".turn_back").click(function(){
     $(".box3").hide();
     $(".box1_content").animate({height:'100px'}, 300,function(){
         $(".box2").show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 500);
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the second animation from the call back of the first one,

```
$(".turn_next").click(function(){
    $(".box2").hide();
    $(".box1_content").animate({height:'300px'}, 300);
    $(".box3").show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 500);
 });

 $(".turn_back").click(function(){
    $(".box3").hide();
    $(".box1_content").animate({height:'100px'}, 300);
    $(".box2").show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 500);
 });
```

The animation effect which you have specified in the `call back function` only get fired only after the initial animation completed. That's why you are seeing that effect.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vHcXN/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're passing a function as an argument to animate, it's being used as a callback for after the animation finishes.  Just call them successively:

http://jsfiddle.net/wyE92/

```
$(".turn_next").click(function(){
   $(".box2").hide();
   $(".box1_content").animate({height:'300px'}, 300);
   $(".box3").show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 500);
});

$(".turn_back").click(function(){
   $(".box3").hide();
   $(".box1_content").animate({height:'100px'}, 300);
   $(".box2").show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 500);
});
```

Note that they don't sync up exactly because you passed different lengths to the animations.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you've got the `.show('slide'...` function firing as a complete callback for when the `.animate({'left'...` function completes. Remove the callback and apply the second animation below the first:

```
$(".turn_next").click(function(){
   $(".box2").hide();
   $(".box1_content").animate({height:'300px'}, 300);
   $(".box3").show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 500);
});

$(".turn_back").click(function(){
   $(".box3").hide();
   $(".box1_content").animate({height:'100px'}, 300);
   $(".box2").show('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 500);
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vHcXN/2/) is your edited fiddle showing the new animations together. Note that because of the different time lengths the two animations do not line up.